# Errors when try to delete allocated array l_sorted and r_sorted in c++

Tags: c++, recursion

Here is my code to implement mergesort algorithm.

It works and it's efficient. But it occurs an error when I try to delete allocated array l_sorted and r_sorted.
The error says: malloc: *** error for object 0x7fa7b3501330: pointer being freed was not allocated
I searched a lot, but didn't find any solution.

How can i fix this ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void merge(int L[],int R[],int size,int *a_sorted, bool even)
{
    if (even == 1)
    {
        int l=0,r=0;
        for (int i=0;i<size*2;i++)
        {
            if ((L[l]<=R[r] && l<size) || (r>=size && l<size))
            {
                a_sorted[i]=L[l];
                l++;
            }
            else
            {
                a_sorted[i]=R[r];
                r++;
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        int l=0,r=0;
        for (int i=0;i<size*2+1;i++)
        {
            if ((L[l]<=R[r] && l<size) || (r>=size+1 && l<size))
            {
                a_sorted[i]=L[l];
                l++;
            }
            else
            {
                a_sorted[i]=R[r];
                r++;
            }
        }
    }
}

int* merge_sort(int a[],int size,int *a_sorted)
{
    if (size == 1)
        return a;

    if(size%2==0)
    {
        int mid=size/2;
        int *L=(a);
        int *R=(a+mid);
        int *l_sorted=new int[mid];
        int *r_sorted=new int[mid];
        l_sorted = merge_sort(L,mid,l_sorted);
        r_sorted = merge_sort(R,mid,r_sorted);
        merge(l_sorted,r_sorted,mid,a_sorted,1);
        delete []l_sorted;
        delete []r_sorted;
    }

    else{
        int mid=size/2;
        int *L=a;
        int *R=a+mid;
        int *l_sorted=new int[mid];
        int *r_sorted=new int[mid+1];
        l_sorted = merge_sort(L,mid,l_sorted);
        r_sorted = merge_sort(R,mid+1,r_sorted);
        merge(l_sorted,r_sorted,mid,a_sorted,0);
        delete []l_sorted;
        delete []r_sorted;
    }


    return a_sorted;
}



int main()
{
    const int s=2;
    clock_t start1=clock();
    int *a=new int[s];
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i=0;i<s;i++){
        a[i]=rand()%(s*2);
    }
    int *b=new int[s];
    clock_t end1=clock();
    clock_t start2=clock();
    b=merge_sort(a,s,b);
    clock_t end2=clock();
    for (int i=0;i<s;i++){
        cout<<b[i]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Time taken for mergesort: "<< (double)(end2-start2)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)<<endl;
    cout<<"Time taken for generate: "<< (double)(end1-start1)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)<<endl;   
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly. Your problem is that `{l,r}_sorted` get assigned different values. `l_sorted = merge_sort(...)`. You have to remember where your original l_sorted was to be able to delete it.

Comment: Since this is tagged c++ maybe you should not use arrays but instead `std::vector` this would make your life easier.

Comment: I have to ask. Why oh why are you making your life so ridiculously difficult by special-casing even-boundary partitions. Not only is there no need to do so, ultimately there is no benefit. The finale of a merge is *always* based on the segment that finished "first" (and one always does, obviously) leaving the remaining list to be simply concatenated. The lhs and rhs segment lengths should simply be `len/2` and `(len - len/2)` If they're identical, so be it, if they're not, who cares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, what is wrong with you code. I'll go into simplifying the algorithm later, but for now... In both chunks of your divide and conquer you do the following:

First, you partition the inbound array into left and right subparts (using the "even" chunk as an example.:

```
int mid=size/2;
int *L=(a);
int *R=(a+mid);
```

then you allocate two arrays of similar size to the partitions.

```
int *l_sorted=new int[mid];
int *r_sorted=new int[mid];
```

finally, you invoke the recursion. Now look carefully at what is being passed as the first parameter:

```
l_sorted = merge_sort(L,mid,l_sorted);
r_sorted = merge_sort(R,mid,r_sorted);
```

But `L` and `R` are not guaranteed to be allocations made in this function. In fact, `R` isn't guaranteed to be allocated in this function **at all**. `R` is always just some offset into the `L` array. Now look what is returned in the **base** case of your recursion (the case where the recursion stops and pops out):

```
if (size == 1)
    return a;
```

This means you're returning either `L` or `R` as the result if the length is 1. but `R` isn't an allocation; its an offset into another array (which *may* be an allocation). So when you do this:

```
r_sorted = merge_sort(R,mid,r_sorted);
```

you just changed what `r_sorted` points to. It no longer points to the allocation you made. Now it points to some offset in the `l_sorted` array from one one step higher in the call-stack. Thus, **boom**. The same thing happens on the `l_sorted` assignment, but in that case when you assign the inbound vector you actually do two things:

1. Leak the original allocation in the same activation scope (the same function call)
2. Delete the *caller's* passed in array (the one passed in as `a[]`

And I should not, Valgrind would catch a ton of this.

If what you're *trying* to do is a top-down merge sort, there are considerably easier ways. but traditional bottom-up is much easier to comprehend, which is shown next.

---

**A Traditional Bottom-Up Merge Sort**

Rare is the time, when coding a recursive algorithm, that throwing *more* code at the problem results in anything besides a bigger problem, and this is no exception to that. You've made this entirely too complicated. Starting with your merge function.

Merge should take three parameters. A segment base, a mid point offset and a total overall length:

```
void merge(int ar[], int mid, int len)
```

There are two segments being sorted:

```
a[0] ... a[mid-1]
a[mid] ... a[len-1]
```

The amount of temporary space required to do this with non-inplace merging is `len` (believe me; you don't want to bite off trying to code the in-place algorithm at this point). The even-boundary specialization code is utterly unnecessary. As hard as it is to believe, the following is the *hardest* part of traditional merge-sort, and there isn't much here at all:

**`merge()` : The Long Version**

```
void merge(int a[], int mid, int len)
{
    int *tmp = new int[len];
    int i=0, j=mid, k=0;

    while (i<mid && j<len)
    {
        // x will reference the index (i or j) we're bumping
        int& x = (a[i] < a[j]) ? i : j;
        tmp[k++] = a[x++];
    }

    // one of the two segments didn't finish. we don't really care which
    //  one, as we'll be ensuring *both* did.
    while (i < mid)
        tmp[k++] = a[i++];
    while (j < len)
        tmp[k++] = a[j++];

    // tmp[] is now fully sorted. just dump the content back
    //  into a[]; *all of it*.
    for (i=0; i<len; ++i)
        a[i] = tmp[i];

    // delete temp space
    delete [] tmp;
}
```

**`merge()` : The Shorter Version**

```
void merge(int a[], int mid, int len)
{
    std::vector<int> tmp;
    tmp.reserve(len);
    std::merge(a, a+mid, a+mid, a+len, std::back_inserter(tmp));
    std::copy(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), a);
}
```

**`merge()` : The Shortest Version**

Don't write a merge *at all* and just use:

```
std::inplace_merge(a, a+len/2, a+len);
```

---

Regardless of which you use, the resulting merge sort algorithm becomes the following, again, with all the even vs. odd partition logic squelched. Note this uses simple pointer arithmetic to specify the rhs-segment starting location, which is always `a+len/2`

```
void mergesort(int a[], int len)
{
    if (len < 2)
        return;

    mergesort(a, len/2);
    mergesort(a+len/2, len-len/2);
    merge(a, len/2, len); // or use std::inplace_merge(a, a+len/2, a+len);
}
```

Now you just have to invoke this properly from `main()`

```
int main()
{
    clock_t start1=clock();

    static const int N = 30;
    int a[N];

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % (2*N);
        std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    clock_t end1=clock();

    mergesort(a,N);
    clock_t end2=clock();

    for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
        std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout<<"Time taken for generate: "<< (double)(end1-start1)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Time taken for mergesort: "<< (double)(end2-end1)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Output** (obviously varies)

```
18 26 38 55 12 38 31 35 46 32 14 26 42 3 10 13 37 21 24 21 11 15 55 10 55 19 47 19 28 53 
3 10 10 11 12 13 14 15 18 19 19 21 21 24 26 26 28 31 32 35 37 38 38 42 46 47 53 55 55 55 
Time taken for generate: 6.1e-05
Time taken for mergesort: 1e-05
```

I can only hope that helped *somehow*. There are obvious ways to make this more efficient, some more obvious than others. For example you *know* you will never need more than `len` extra space, so you could allocate the *entire* temp space before the algorithm dives in and parameterize it with every call thereafter. This would eliminate all but one memory allocation. You could further make this RAII-based by using smarter allocation (such as was demonstrated with the shorter `merge()` algorithm using a `std::vector<>`. Just food for thought.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful advise. 
I'm new to programming, there're a lot I can learn from your implementation.
But Could you help to point out why my delete[]l_sorted / delete[]r_sorted doesn't work??
Thank you in advance

Comment: @Young certainly. I'll update the question. I'll need a minute: